# how to write a for loop with python pandas fro url, api and date constraint

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to get my code to work but I can't. What I am trying to do is to get the data from a website with an api code. The goal is get the information from certain date (in this case from 2000 to 2003)

```
import requests
import json


url ='https://opendata.aemet.es/opendata/api/valores/climatologicos/diarios/datos/' 
start= 'fechaini/2000-01-01T00:00:00UTC/'
end = 'fechafin/2003-01-01T00:00:00UTC/' 
station= 'estacion/1690A/'
api= 'xxxxxxxxx'

complete_url=url+start+end+station+api
print(complete_url)

response = requests.get(complete_url)

data_url = json.loads(response.text)['datos']

data = requests.get(data_url)
data.text
json.loads(data.text)
```

Now I am trying to write a for loop for the code above. Basically just iterating from 2000 to 2003 and save in into a csv file.

This is what I tried

```
responses = list()
station = '1690A'


for station in stations:
   rr = requests.get(data_url)
   data=json.loads(rr.text)
   responses.append(data)
```

But then, where do I put the date constraint and how do I turn it into a csv file

Thanks for the help

Edit: sample json

```
{'fecha': '2000-01-01',
  'indicativo': '1690A',
  'nombre': 'OURENSE',
  'provincia': 'OURENSE',
  'altitud': '143',
  'tmed': '3,2',
  'prec': '0,0',
  'tmin': '-2,4',
  'horatmin': '08:45',
  'tmax': '8,8',
  'horatmax': '16:25',
  'dir': '14',
  'velmedia': '0,6',
  'racha': '3,9',
  'horaracha': '08:18',
  'sol': '4,2',
  'presMax': '1012,7',
  'horaPresMax': '11',
  'presMin': '1009,9',
  'horaPresMin': '15'},
 {'fecha': '2000-01-02',
  'indicativo': '1690A',
  'nombre': 'OURENSE',
  'provincia': 'OURENSE',
  'altitud': '143',
  'tmed': '2,7',
  'prec': '0,0',
  'tmin': '-2,4',
  'horatmin': '08:40',
  'tmax': '7,8',
  'horatmax': '16:30',
  'dir': '14',
  'velmedia': '0,6',
  'racha': '3,6',
  'horaracha': '09:56',
  'sol': '3,7',
  'presMax': '1012,2',
  'horaPresMax': '10',
  'presMin': '1009,7',
  'horaPresMin': 'Varias'},
 {'fecha': '2000-01-03',
  'indicativo': '1690A',
  'nombre': 'OURENSE',
  'provincia': 'OURENSE',
  'altitud': '143',
  'tmed': '4,2',
  'prec': '0,0',
  'tmin': '-1,6',
  'horatmin': '08:20',
  'tmax': '10,0',
  'horatmax': '16:00',
  'dir': '15',
  'velmedia': '0,6',
  'racha': '2,8',
  'horaracha': '07:40',
  'sol': '4,2',
  'presMax': '1011,7',
  'horaPresMax': '11',
  'presMin': '1008,7',
  'horaPresMin': '16'},
```

Comment: pandas has a to_csv() function, no?

Comment: true true. For me here the hard part would be to write in a loop format taking into account the date constraint.

Comment: Will it contain all the dates between that range? Are you trying to create a single row for each date in csv?? Also please add a sample json response for better clarity.

Comment: Done. It is in below the question. Any help would be great.

Yes, it will contain all the dates. It would be great to have rows with the date and the the rest of the data next to each other. Then in the second row the second date with all the data next to it.

Answer (score 1):

That should be easy to do. Leveraging so pandas, here is the solution.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
def get_csv(jsonData, startingDate, endingDate, csvFilename):
    startingDate = dt.strptime(startingDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    endingDate = dt.strptime(endingDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    csvJson = []
    for each in jsonData:
        try: 
            if startingDate <= dt.strptime(each['fecha'], '%Y-%m-%d') <= endingDate: 
                csvJson.append(each) 
        except: 
            pass
    pd.DataFrame(csvJson).to_csv(csvFilename)
```

Call the function like following

`>>> get_csv(jsonData, '2000-01-03', '2001-04-23', 'test.csv')`

This shall put the between date range ['2000-01-03' and '2001-04-23'] into a csv file named 'test.csv'.

Hope this works well.